# Saving Model with hasOne association

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I've got these models :

```
Ext.define('TestApp.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'username', type: 'string'},
        ],

        proxy: {
           type: 'localstorage',
        },
    },
});

Ext.define('TestApp.model.Config', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {

        hasOne  : {model: 'TestApp.model.User', name: 'user'},

        proxy: {
           type: 'localstorage',
        },

    }
});
```

I've tried to save a config entry like this :

```
    var david = Ext.create('TestApp.model.User', {username: 'david'})
    david.save();
    var config = Ext.create('TestApp.model.Config');
    config.setUser(david);
    config.save();
```

When I restart the application, I have my **user entry saved** and my **config entry saved** but, **my association is not saved**:

**config.getUser()** -> I get *undefined*

Comment: Im sure `hasMany` mapping is not supported in localstorage proxy's. Could be possible that mapping in general is not supported (in ST2)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mitchell Simoens](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?190000-Has-Many-with-localstorage&p=762500&viewfull=1#post762500) storing associated data isn't supported.

Unsure if it helps in your case, but [an approach is sketched](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?220305-Problem-with-localstorage-store-and-model-with-hasMany-association&p=835806&viewfull=1#post835806) (that approach also seems to adress my own current (unrelated) problem).

Hope it helps